# How to use dummy variables for categorical variables in a multiple regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

If I have a categorical variable with three levels (`CatXVar`) that I recode into two dummy variables (`NYXVar` and `BostonXVar`)such that:

```
YVar ContXVar  CatXVar NYXVar BostonXVar
0.23 10        NY      1      0
0.1  22.3      Boston  0      1
0.52 11.9      London  0      0
```

and I want to see whether `CatXVar` affects the significance of any relationship between `YVar` and `ContXVar`, should I run two separate regressions of:

```
Yvar ~ ContXVar + NYXVar
```

and

```
Yvar ~ ContXVar + BostonXVar
```

or should I run the regression as:

```
Yvar ~ ContXVar + NYXVar + BostonXVar
```

Comment: If you exclude the intercept from your model you can run it using CarXVar as the predictor.

Comment: I've read that I should convert k-level categorical variables into k-1 binary dummy variables though?

Comment: Not if you don't have an intercept.

Comment: How do I get rid of the intercept in R with glm?

Comment: You can remove the intercept by including `-1` in the model specification. You might want to consider reading [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-lm) before doing that. `Yvar ~ ContXVar + NYXVar + BostonXVar` seems to be the safe bet here.

Comment: Yeah why not. Added it as answer. Might trigger some useful feedback/insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the intercept, as suggested in the comments, by including `-1` in the model specification. 
However, you might want to consider reading [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-lm) before doing that.

`Yvar ~ ContXVar + NYXVar + BostonXVar` seems to be the safe bet here.

Running two separate regressions essentially means you're estimating two separate models as you don't account for the New York/Boston effect respectively.